# How can I restrict google places SearchBox api to only return results of a specified Country?

Tags: google-maps

I want the searchbox should only returns results from Spain country. I specified the country but it shows results from other countries also.

`   const input = document.querySelector('.location-search-input');

```
const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
    componentRestrictions: { country: "es" },
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
    types: ["geocode"],
    strictBounds: true,
});
```

`

[search results for "monasterios de sanata maria"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecys5.png)